# Geolocation API JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geolocation, global

I try to alert my latitude and longitude, but it's doesn't work. 
I create a global variables, and change this variables in function. I my other functions not sees this **global variables**. I don't know, what is the error.

```
var latitdue;
var longitude;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(     
function coords(position) {
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;          
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
}, function (error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code);
},
{
    enableHighAccuracy : false,     
    timeout : 10000,                
    maximumAge : 1000           
});
function a(){
    alert(longitude, latitude);
}
a();
```

Comment: The geoloaction API is asynchronous, so you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

its a typo error "latitude" not var latitdue
change 
var latitdue; 
to 
var latitude

and "Allow" the popup or hint on browser bar for accessing computer's location

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var latitude;
            var longitude;

            function a(){

            if (navigator.geolocation)
             {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(     
                function coords(position) {
                    longitude = position.coords.longitude;          
                    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    alert("Lat Long is : " + longitude +"," + latitude);
                }, function (error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code);
                },
                {
                    enableHighAccuracy : true,     
                    timeout : 10000,                
                    maximumAge : 1000           
                });

               }
               else
               {
                alert ("GEOLOCATION NOT SUPPORTED....");
               }
            }
            //a(); 



            </script>
            </head>
            <body onLoad="a();">
            TESTING GEOLOCATION
            </body>
```

You will have to call the method after loading success.

Also, Allow for share location.

Comment: In IE8, GEOLOCATION NOT SUPPORTED.... is the response. In firefox, my current latitude longitude is displayed correctly with the above code.  Don't forget to add  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>